# MAX Function Fails in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to get the MOST recent date that comes before tom_temp.Begin_Time out of tbl_Trim_history.Comp.  The SQL I'm using is:

```
SELECT
    Tom_Temp2.feeder,
    Tom_Temp.CauseType,
    Tom_Temp.RootCause,
    Tom_Temp.Storm_Name_Thunder,
    Tom_Temp.DeviceGroup,
    tbl_Trim_History.[COMP],
    Tom_Temp.[Begin_Time]

FROM Tom_Temp2

LEFT JOIN (Tom_Temp
LEFT JOIN tbl_Trim_History
    ON Tom_Temp.feeder = tbl_Trim_History.CIRCUIT_ID)

    ON Tom_Temp2.feeder = Tom_Temp.feeder

WHERE (((tbl_Trim_History.[COMP]) < [Tom_Temp].[Begin_Time]));
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out where I need to put my max() function in this statement in order to make sure I don't get back every single tbl_Trim_history.[COMP] that occurs prior to the tom_temp.Begin_Time date.  I only want the most recent date from tbl_Trim_history.[COMP] that occurs BEFORE the tom_temp.begin_Time .... NOT every historical date record.

Any help you guys could give me would be awesome because I keep getting back sets that I can tell are not what I'm looking for / expecting.

Thanks everyone. I appreciate the feedback.

**Edit in regard to the responses below:**

Due to the character limits, I just edited the master post for you guys.

I can't really post the data as it is somewhat confidential, so the best I can do is give you an example.  Also, this is access, but my background is MySQL. Sorry for the tags, I wasn't sure what was similar since the access tag just didn't seem to fit the question.

The Data being received are about 168 records.  Someone pointed out that there is an inner join occurring here, but I wanted to indicate I'm actually using 3 different tables.

1 table contains my feeders,

Another contains a list of all outages that I am joining to using all my feeders contained in the first table

Then I have another table that contains all the trim history for each feeder.  The outage table is joined to the trim table.

When I run the query above, I get data like this

```
feeder    |   comp      |       Begin_time
___________________________________________

123456  |   10/4/2012   |    3/3/2016 11:26:00AM
123456  |   10/17/2015  |    3/3/2016 11:26:00AM

456789  |    6/28/2008  |    9/20/2013 10:05AM
456789  |    12/1/2012  |    9/20/2013 10:05AM
456789  |    7/3/2013   |    9/20/2013  10:05AM
```

what I want is data like this:

```
 feeder    |   comp      |       Begin_time
    ___________________________________________

    123456  |   10/17/2015  |    3/3/2016 11:26:00AM

    456789  |    7/3/2013   |    9/20/2013  10:05AM
```

where the comp date is the closest to date / time occuring BEFORE Begin_time date.

I tried this query:

```
SELECT Tom_Temp2.feeder, Tom_Temp.CauseType, Tom_Temp.RootCause, Tom_Temp.Storm_Name_Thunder, Tom_Temp.DeviceGroup, Max(tbl_Trim_History.COMP) AS MaxOfCOMP, Tom_Temp.Begin_Time

FROM Tom_Temp2 

LEFT JOIN (Tom_Temp LEFT JOIN tbl_Trim_History ON Tom_Temp.feeder = tbl_Trim_History.CIRCUIT_ID) ON Tom_Temp2.feeder = Tom_Temp.feeder

GROUP BY Tom_Temp2.feeder, Tom_Temp.CauseType, Tom_Temp.RootCause, Tom_Temp.Storm_Name_Thunder, Tom_Temp.DeviceGroup, Tom_Temp.Begin_Time
HAVING (((Max(tbl_Trim_History.COMP))<[Tom_Temp].[Begin_Time]));
```

But of the 168 records I get back in my first query, I'm only getting back 20 records with this query.

The reason I know this is wrong is because some records are missing between the set of 168 and the set of 20.   For example, I'd be missing any records for feeder 456789. However, I ***know*** this record should be returned because it's in my table of feeders that should be returned (Tom_Temp2).

After manually deleting unwanted rows of data, I know that I should get a record count of 85.  So my most recent attempt to use the Max query is way off.

Comment: mysql or sql-server? both are different dbs

Comment: I have removed the tags for sql-server and mysql please tag only the rdmbs that you are using

Comment: In addition you may want to add some sample data and desired outcome based on that data in addition so that your desired logic can be inferred better as your description leaves some questions.  Next becasuse you are using your tbl_trim_history table in your where clause you in affect have an inner join not the LEFT JOIN you specify

Comment: You mentioned you keep getting results that are not what you are expecting.  It would be helpful if you'd provide a sample of your current results based on the query you've provided along with your expected results.

Comment: Added some information above and fixed the tags.  Sorry about that, I posted this before I left work so I didn't see the comments till this morning.  Not sure if anyone here was the one who downrated, but I hope this clarifies the situation and changes your minds.

I'm just used to working in MySQL and MS SQL.  I got hosed with this access database and I didn't want the question to be misconstrued as a vba based inquiry.  Hence why I miffed up the tags on this one.  I'll stick to MS access tags for questions like this in the future, and just make sure I clarify in the question.

Comment: Good sample data is a close relative of [mcve]. It shows the problem with a minimum of columns and rows. It isn't supposed to be real data (which is usually too complicated and has too little variations). Your query should be simplified as much as possible too - a minimum of columns and criteria that still shows the problem. And please rename the tables, names like `Tom_Temp` and `Tom_Temp2` in non-trivial SQL creates headaches for the readers (us).

Comment: Oh, and you can use http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to easily add formatted sample data to your question.

Comment: Sorry about the names Andre, I intend to delete these tables when I am done so they don't have very meaningful names.  I'll do a find and replace next time to help increase the clarity.

Also thanks for the ascii table link.  I always wondered how people had such nice looking data samples on this site.

Comment: Cool. But don't wait for "next time" - do it for this question. Plus the sample data. Assuming you still want an answer. :)